# Locked on stock recovery software?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode

Even after flashing clockworkmod, when I go into the recovery menu after booting, it just gives me the stock recovery system. Help? I've also tried with twrp, no luck.

Comment: I had this problem with me while flashing Oneplus One with Philz Touch Recovery. Same issue. I factory reset my phone and the issue was gone. However, please confirm do you have any option like `Settings > Developer Options > Update Recovery`. If you have anything regarding recovery there, please mention it here. And perhaps, it would be better if you can mention the Device model, Recovery Version, Steps used for installing recovery.

Comment: @Firelord , No, I don't have an option like that. Device model: `SAMSUNG-SGH-1337` Recovery version: I'm using ClockworkMod 6.0.4.7 Steps used: I just flashed it in ROM manager. Please help?

Comment: Using `ROM Manager` to successfully install recovery requires Root Access. Please explain how did you even rooted your device without installing custom recovery first? Which OS do you have now in your PC? We'll be using PC now to install recovery using conventional method.

Comment: I installed with Odin on my PC. Edit: I'm using windows

Comment: Samsung makes thing complicated. ADB is so much easy over anything. As my experience is with ADB only with no Samsung devices, I can recommend [this.](http://techbeasts.com/2014/06/30/root-and-install-cwm-recovery-on-att-samsung-galaxy-s4-sgh-i337-running-android-4-4-2-kit-kat/)

Comment: @Firelord can you chat with me somehow? I would really like some help...

Comment: @Firelord By the way, I'm using 4.4.4 KitKat

Comment: Is your Bootloader unlocked?

Comment: @Firelord I don't believe it is... Is there any chance this could brick my phone, or is it just a reset?

Comment: Well, technically, if you try installing recovery you can end up bricking your phone very easily if you aren't aware of the know-how's of the things you're using. `ROM Manager` is dangerous because in case of bricking you'll not come to know what went wrong. ADB/Fastboot helps people in this regard.Are you sure you want to install Custom recovery at this point or you want to learn more and then try installing it.

Comment: You can reset the phone easily by going into your current stock recovery. That's easy and safe.

Comment: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85371/rom-flashing-using-odin-on-galaxy-s4-interrupted-odin-is-still-running-is-ther) question's asker already knows about installing custom recovery on S4. You can ping him.

Comment: @Adi Inbar Your help is needed here! Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because most stock systems will flash the stock recovery on boot and/or your bootloader is locked (and prevents writing to safe partitions).

Please follow this instructions from CM; They are working, I already tested them:
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_jflte#Recovery_Installation

Comment: Thanks. However, I saw few questions where answerer referred links like you did, but was advised by senior members not do so since the link can be broken or down in the future, thereby, making the answer useless for anyone looking for answer. But your reputation is already high. Anyway :)

Comment: Since this is a site on the official CM servers, I don't think that it will go down in the near future... ;)

Comment: I did give a thought to that while writing but then, may be some new member lurking around like me might notice and learn from it in the near future. :)

Comment: @TimoS the goo.im link to the to the loki files isn't working for me. Is there any other way I could get to them?

Comment: @Firelord do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @JoakimPoops Do you mean the GApps?

Comment: @TimoS Crap. Did some troubleshooting, it seems there's no way to flash ROMs on my device... ATT locked down against loki with the 4.4.4 KitKat update... If I unlock my phone, will that make this easier? (Unlock with unlock code from ATT)? Btw, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoakimPoops Yes you have to unlock your phone to continue...

Comment: @TimoS if I unlock it, can I launch the custom recoveries as easily as on a non-brand samsung?

Comment: @JoakimPoops You should, yes. But your warranty is void then. But I don't think that's a problem...

Comment: @TimoS Alright, I'll working on getting a code. Get back to you soon! Thanks for the help thus far!

Answer (score 0):

You most probably using odin and cwm or twrp tar.md5 file to flash new recovery to a Samsung device. Key point in here is that untick the reboot after flash in odin settings and remove battery after flash completed. This way original recovery doesnt have time to reinstall.